# Python Error : 'RPCProxy' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have python 2.6 installed on a linux machine. (CentOS - Cloudera VM)

When I try this in idle:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print (line)

Error :   'RPCProxy' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working from an interactive terminal `sys.stdin` is not a typical file handle like you'd expect if you were to invoke your script by calling `python.exe myscript.py`.  You won't be able to iterate over it like this from the idle prompt.

```
>>> sys.stdin
<idlelib.PyShell.PseudoInputFile object at 0x02D76830>
```

Comment: Kind of ... on my system in idle if run that for loop it seems to execute, but indefinitely, and I have to break out with a keyboard interrupt.

Comment: yea I agreed. I am internally trying to use hadoop streaming API since it will read a file and dump to std.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: that's the definition of "works". it supposed to do that. you have to signal the end of file.

Comment: `sys.stdin` may have been not iterable in Python 2.6's version of IDLE, but it appears to be iterable in IDLE included with recent Python (3.6+).